# Parsing XML to get all child nodes and their data using Java XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Hi I have requirement like parsing xml and get all child nodes and there data between nodes `<Employees>` and `</Employees>`

I have xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee emplid="1111" type="admin">
        <firstname>test1</firstname>
        <lastname>Watson</lastname>
        <age>30</age>
        <email>johnwatson@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee emplid="2222" type="admin">
        <firstname>Sherlock</firstname>
        <lastname>Homes</lastname>
        <age>32</age>
        <email>sherlock@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I need response like

```
<Employee emplid="1111" type="admin">
        <firstname>test1</firstname>
        <lastname>Watson</lastname>
        <age>30</age>
        <email>johnwatson@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee emplid="2222" type="admin">
        <firstname>Sherlock</firstname>
        <lastname>Homes</lastname>
        <age>32</age>
        <email>sherlock@sh.com</email>
    </Employee>
```

I have tried below code

```
 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\test.xml"));

         DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

         DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

         Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

         XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

         System.out.println("*************************");
         String expression = "/Employees/*";
         System.out.println(expression);
         String email = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
         System.out.println(email);
```

but I am getting response like

```
  test1
        Watson
        30
        johnwatson@sh.com
```

I have used expression like **/Employees/*** but its not working

can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: The XPath expression is correct to select all child elements of the root element. However, to serialize a node back to a string of markup, you need to use the DOM Level 3 Load and Save API or a default transformer.

Comment: so can't we do it using simple xpath?? if you are having any working code can u share?

Comment: XPath 1.0 and 2.0 don't serialize nodes, no, in XPath 3.0 you can use http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize, e.g. `/Employees/*/serialize(.)` to get a sequence of strings. But the Oracle Java JRE does not support XPath 3.0 and the API you use is not designed for XPath 2.0 or 3.0 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to match each `Employee`, ideally your XPath expression should be `Employee` not `/Employees/*`. If you know the tag name, you also don't need XPath, you can just do `xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("Employee")`.

If you want to serialize a node to a String, you can use an `Transformer`, something like this:

```
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newTransformer();
NodeList nodes = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    t.transform(new DOMSource(nodes.item(i)), new StreamResult(sw));
    String serialized = sw.toString();
    System.out.println(serialized);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a possible XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="Employees">
   <xsl:copy-of select = "Employee" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize a DOM node to a string use e.g.

```
import  org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry;
import  org.w3c.dom.Document;
import  org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import  org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;

...

DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();

DOMImplementationLS impl = 
    (DOMImplementationLS)registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");

LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
String str = writer.writeToString(node);
```

So returning a `NodeList` you could use

```
     String expression = "/Employees/*";
     System.out.println(expression);
     NodeList elements = (NodeList)xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
     for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) 
     {
       System.out.println(writer.writeToString(element.item(i));
     }
```